# Print offset as hex, but in 'two digits' pairs

Tags: c

I want to print the first 6 digits of my variable 'offset' as hex, but firstly the first two digits, then the next two digits and the last to digits. I want to print each time a specific area of my offset.

```
uint32_t offset = 0;
//iterate offset to a specific point
printf("%06X ", offset);
//result is for example 989680
```

What I want:

```
uint32_t offset = 0;
//iterate offset to a specific point
printf("%02X", offset);
printf("%02X", offset);
printf("%02X ", offset);
//result should be 989680 but is logically 989898
```

The printout statement in the last code has to be three times, not in one statement

```
//I dont want this
printf("%02X, %02X, %02X ", offset);
```

I think I have to do this with a pointer but I'm fairly new in c.

Comment: Use a mask for that

Comment: 989680 can't be a uint16_t...

Comment: The range of an uint16_t in hex is 0x0000 to 0xFFFF. You'll never get 6 digits out of your "offset" value.

Comment: `uint32_t offset = 989898; printf("%02" PRIX32 "\n", offset);`

Comment: Thanks for telling me the uint16_t issue

Comment: Why must this be multiple print statements? Using a single one has a few advantages and no disadvantages I know about.

Comment: It isn't clear from the question what you expect from printing 0x123456.  Is it `123456` or `563412` or something else?  It's partly a question of defining 'first' digits — is it the most significant digits, or the least significant.  If  you want 123456 as the output, then you can use `"%.6X"` (give or take; if you're using `uint32_t`, that should be `"%.6" PRIX32`, strictly).  This will apply regardless of endianness.  If you're looking for something else, or to deal with endianness somehow, you need to explain more precisely what you want.

Comment: My offset is  0x123456 and i want to print  12345

Comment: Basicaly i want to read the strlen() of my buffer. Content of this buffer is also the offset at the beginning. After a specific 'amount of content' (example 512 bytes) i want to call a function. When i do this without locking at each 2 digits, strlen() could be over 512 bytes (for example 510 bytes, thats <512, + 6 hex offset = 518 bytes). So i want to check strleng() after printing %02X each time. May i should open a new question for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hex value is too long for an `uint16_t`, try with `uint32_t`. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t offset = 0x989680;

    printf("%02"PRIX32" ", (offset & 0x00ff0000) >> 16);
    printf("%02"PRIX32" ", (offset & 0x0000ff00) >> 8);
    printf("%02"PRIX32" ", (offset & 0x000000ff) >> 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
98 96 80
```

Comment: Thanks! What exactly is PRIX? What would be a solution for uint16_t instead uint32_t?

Comment: Expands to a character string literal containing a conversion specifier, possibly modified by a length modifier, suitable for use within the format argument of a formatted input/output function when converting the corresponding integer type , more info: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html

Comment: There is no solution for `uint16_t` because your number doesn't fit in a 16 bit integer type :( Consider using an array of 3 `uint8_t`s

Comment: Or: `(offset >> 16) & 0xFF` and `(offset >> 8) & 0xFF` and `(offset >> 0) & 0xFF` where any compiler worth its salt will ignore the shift by 0 even without optimization, but the symmetry is emphasized.  This is simpler because it uses the same mask `0xFF` for all three.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> > |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|
>
> > |0|1|0|1|0|1|1|0|1|0|1 |0 |1 |1 |0 |1 |
> ```

First you need first 4 bits, so shift right 12x

> |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0 |0 **|0 |1 |0 |1 |**

And store it to var1, keep it doing and you got it.

```
uint8_t var1 = (offset >> 12);

uint8_t var2 = (offset >> 8) & 0x0f;

uint8_t var3 = (offset >> 4) & 0x0f;
```